# Compare two Table Column Values in Java

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, maximo

I have a two Tables in Maximo 7.5.

Table A: has attribute WORKORDERNUM, EXPECTEDTIME and FINISHTIME in table A.
Table B: has attribute WORKNUM and STATUS in table B.

What I want to do is: 
if FINISHTIME > EXPECTEDTIME then update STATUS in table B as "NOTGOOD" otherwise do nothing.
I have created a CronTask for that which will be running every five minutes.

Now I can think of is two approaches.

**1.** To loop through all Table A. Inside the loop perform a database query for Table B each time.

Here is the sample code:

```
 MboSetRemote TableA = mxs.getMboSet("TABLEA", ui);
 MboSetRemote TableB = mxs.getMboSet("TABLEB", ui);
 TableA.setWhere("FINISHTIME > EXPECTEDTIME");
 TableA.reset();
 TableB.setWhere("");
 TableB.reset();
 MboSet TableARow = null;
 MboSet TableBRow = null;
 //now it will give  a list of entries. Which needs to be matched with Table B and values be updated in Table B STATUS.
while ((TableARow = TableA.getMbo(i)) != null)
{
 int A = TableA.getString("WONUM");
    while((TableBRow = TableB.getMbo(i)) != null)
      int B = TableB.getString("WONUM");
      if (A == B){
      //set SATUS etc}

 }
TableB.save();
TableA.save();
```

**2.** To loop through all Table A. Inside the loop perform Compare the values for Table B each time.

```
 MboSetRemote TableA = mxs.getMboSet("TABLEA", ui);
 MboSetRemote TableB = mxs.getMboSet("TABLEB", ui);
 TableA.setWhere("FINISHTIME > EXPECTEDTIME");
 TableA.reset();
 MboSet TableARow = null;
 //now it will give  a list of entries. Which needs to be matched with Table B and values be updated in Table B STATUS.
while ((TableARow = TableA.getMbo(i)) != null)
{
 TableB.setWhere("WONUM= TABLEA.WONUM");
 TableB.reset();
//set SATUS etc
 TableB.save();
 }
TableA.save();
```

Which one is the better and more cost effective?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: AhmedRana, if you are satisfied with any of the answers, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Automation scripts are fun to write and use, but they aren't always the best tool for the job. In this case, I would use

1. an `Escalation` to search `TableA` for `FINISHTIME > EXPECTEDTIME`
2. a `Relationship` in `Database Configuration` from `TableA` to `TableB` where `wonum = :wonum and siteid = :siteid`
3. an `Action` based on `TableA` that uses the above `Relationship` in standard notation to set the status in `TableB`

The main benefits of this approach over the ones presented are upgradeability and supportability. Upgradeability, because no code is involved that can be deprecated and because all configurations are upgradeable, and supportability because IBM supports configurations but not customizations. (In the case of Automation Scripts, your ability to write them is supported, but your code, itself, is not. It is the same with Relationships in Database Configuration.)

Answer (score 1):

The most cost effective thing to do here would not be to use a Crontask every 5 minutes, but to perform a check just when every record is changed. This would be much much more efficient.

Make two custom field classes, one for each of the date fields, and attach the to the fields on database configuration.

The one on EXPECTEDTIME should be something like this:

```
public class CustFldExpectedTime extends MboValueAdapter {

        public CustFldExpectedTime(MboValue mbv) throws MXException {
                super(mbv);
        }

        @Override
        public void action() throws MXException, RemoteException {
                super.action();
                MboValue mv = getMboValue();
                MboRemote mbo = mv.getMbo();

                Date expectedTime = mv.getDate();
                Date finishTime = mbo.getDate("FINISHTIME");

                if(finishTime.after(expectedTime)) {
                        // first argument is the name of on-the-fly relationship
                        // second argument is the name of the table your relationship is pointing to
                        // third argument is the relationship where clause
                        MboSetRemote tableBSet = mbo.getMboSet("$TABLEB", "TABLEB", ":WORKORDERNUM = WORKNUM");
                        if(!tableBSet.isEmpty()) {
                                MboRemote tableB = tableBSet.getMbo(0);
                                tableB.setValue("STATUS", "NOTGOOD");
                        }
                }
        }
}
```